XAMPP not running on Mac OS 12.7.5 - Syntax Error
I'm trying to launch the Apache Web Server on my copy of XAMPP (8.1.17) and it won't turn on. I have tried the following (all listed in THIS THREAD):

sudo killall httpd in Terminal
changing ports in the httpf.conf file from 80 to 8080
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist returns a
Unload failed: 5: Input/Output error
Turned off Bluebooth
Kill all HTTPD processes in Activity Monitor

but when I try sudo apachectl stop in the terminal I recieve this error:
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp.so, 0x000A): Symbol not found: (_iconv)\n  Referenced from: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp.so'\n  Expected in: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libiconv.2.dylib'
I'm figuring THIS is the reason I can't launch Apache Web Server in XAMPP, but I have no idea how to resolve it.
Thank you in advance.

Content of the config files? My "guess" is something related to libphp.so/php. Try to comment that out. Because you didnt post the content of the config files, cant tell you exactly what line, but: "modules/libphp.so" & "Syntax error on line 3 of ..." should be enough to find the right place. If apache starts, then you have problem with your php installation.

All that's on Line 3 of httpd-xampp.conf is: LoadModule php_module        modules/libphp.so -- I commented it out, now Apache runs, but MySQL Database does not.

Did you do what i wrote? Comment that line and try to start Apache?

edited comment with results
